# Read and Write from Memory in LabVIEW FPGA simultaneously?

Tags: memory, fpga, labview, lookup-tables

Is it possible to access the same data in a target scoped memory lookup table defined in LabVIEW FPGA to write and read at the same time within a single cycle timed loop or does this lead to undefined behavior of the VI?

Comment: Why are you required to read and write to the same data in a single cycle? Would this not just be the same as wiring data from one position to another?

I would highly expect this situation to be dependent on your implementation, if you can enforce the order of reading/writing then it should be possible to handle without risk.

Comment: Probably yes. Wait - is it possible to enforce the order of reading and writing within a single cycle? I am not required to do it, but it can happen in my current implementation and I am wondering if that could be a problem.

Comment: LabVIEW (even in the FPGA ) is a data-flow language. So through standard LabVIEW practice of enforcing data-flow (passing through references, errors or even sequence structures ) you can ensure that the write always occurs before the read. However there are additional considerations to be taken regarding the limitation of a single-cycle process.